# Upload files to userContent of jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a multi-branch pipeline job from which I would like to upload a file to the Jenkins userContent location using a Groovy script. I tried the [job-dsl-plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/userContent) to use `userContent` method, but it throws the error shown below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'userContent' found among steps
```

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands

Do I need to configure anything in order to upload a file to userContent? Is there any other way to upload a file to the userContent location?

Answer (score 2):

You can not simply mix Pipeline DSL and Job DSL. See [Use Job DSL in Pipeline scripts](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#use-job-dsl-in-pipeline-scripts) for instructions on using the Job DSL build step as a Pipeline step.

```
node {
  jobDsl scriptText: 'userContent("test.txt", new ByteArrayInputStream("test".bytes))'
}
```